# Nullable DateTime setting it getting invalid argument with cannot convert to long

Tags: c#, datetime, nullable

Why do I need to set DateTime as Nullable like this?

```
DateTime? Err_Rpt_Tm = new DateTime?(DateTime.Now);

Console.WriteLine(Err_Rpt_Tm);
```

Because I find it odd that in Linqpad when I do this

```
DateTime Err_Rpt_Tm = new DateTime(DateTime.Now);
```

**I get this error**

`The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.DateTime(long)' has some invalid arguments`

`Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.DateTime' to 'long'`

1. DateTime.Now is never going to be null, so I don't understand the need for nullable  DateTime?
2. convert System.DateTime to long???  I'm explicitly setting DateTime variable "Err_Rpt_Tm"

Comment: You can simply use `DateTime? Err_Rpt_Tm = DateTime.Now;`instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateTime?` is a short-hand for `Nullable<DateTime>`. Let's look at [documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx). In constructors section the only available constructor is `Nullable<T>(T)`. This explains why first part of your code compiles.

In second case you are trying to initialize `DateTime`, and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) clearly states that there is no constructor, that accepts single parameter of type `DateTime`. This is why you get a compile error in second case.

To fix the issue you can use much simpler form of initialization:

```
DateTime? Err_Rpt_Tm = DateTime.Now;
DateTime Err_Rpt_Tm2 = DateTime.Now;
```

This is possible because `Nullable<T>` implements [operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx#Anchor_4) for converting nullable type to / from actual type.

Answer (score 0):

No DateTime constructor accepts DateTime object although it has constructor for long i.e. [DateTime(long ticks)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk(v=vs.110).aspx) and error is suggesting that constructor to be used.

You can directly assign DateTime.Now to DateTime object and do not need a constructor for this.

```
DateTime Err_Rpt_Tm = DateTime.Now;
```

To assign to Nullable DateTime

```
DateTime? Err_Rpt_Tm = DateTime.Now;
```